# Error al retornar un data desde Controller php a un Ajax en jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, php, ajax

Tengo un problema al retornar un dato desde un `Controllers/registro` en `php` a un `Ajax`. El controller recibe un dato desde un `Model/registro.php`, pero el mismo no retorna al `Ajax` ese dato que recibe.

¿Cuál pordría ser el motivo por el cual `Controller/registro.php` no retorna ningún dato al `Ajax`, a pesar de que sí realiza el insert en el `Model/registro.php`?

#### Model/registro.php

```
public function registrar($username, $email, $password, $confirm_password)
{                                 
    try
    { 
        $this->has = crypt($password);
        $this->has_con = crypt($confirm_password);
        $p= "soy diferente de uno";

        $registro = $this->conexion->conexion->query("insert into registro_por (nombre, correo, pass, conf_pass) values( '$username', '$email', '$this->has', '$this->has_con')");

        if ($registro)
        {
            return $p;                            
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Fallos la ejecución");                     
        }


    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'Message: '.$e->getMessage();
    }         
}
```

#### Controllers/registro.php

```
require_once("../Model/registro.php");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$confirm_password = $_POST["confirm_password"];      

$reg = new Registro();
$t = $reg->registrar($username, $email, $password, $confirm_password);  

var_dump($t);

if ($t != 1)
{
    //return "ok";
    //echo "es difenrete de uno";
    return $t;
}
else
{
    return $t;
    //echo "fail";
}
```

#### JavaScript

`Ajax` `jQuery` recibe el data del controlador:

```
$('#register-submit').click(function () {      

    var data = $('#register-form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () {
            console.log(data);
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../Controllers/registro.php',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('nanananana');
            console.log("soy data"+data);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: ¿Qué valores obtienes en el `var_dump`?¿Hay algún error en la consola de JS?¿Es `$this->conexion->conexion->query` correcto o debería ser `$this->conexion->query`? (aunque esta última no debería importar mucho porque debería estar bien si funciona e inserta en la base de datos)

Comment: Por cierto, a no ser que los parámetros que pasas al query se saneen y hayas borrado esa parte, el código de arriba es vulnerable a ataques de inyección de SQL y no debería ser usado en páginas web de cara al público o podrías tener problemas.

Comment: Hola buenos días, gracias por responder, usualmente  uso esta función pero esta vez la pase por alto porque la tarea era sencilla.
Use esta lineas para captar el error:
-error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow){

                        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
    
                 alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');
Y el error que me dio  fue este :
Not connect: Verify Network.
Dejo un pastebin con el código completo de la function error,
http://pastebin.com/LB0mFc7G

Comment: A que te refieres con el tema de sanear los datos que se le pasan al query?

Comment: Si alguien pasa esto `'; DROP TABLE registro_por; --` como valor del campo username y no saneas las entradas, entonces el contenido de la tabla se borrará completamente (aunque mejor que eso sería que usaras consultas parametrizadas). Es un ejemplo como el de [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) (chiste en inglés)

Answer (score 1):

No programes a ciegas cuando usas `Ajax`. En tú código no le estás agregando un `log` de error ni un cargando a tu función `jQuery`. Para retornar el error desde `php` agrégale esto:

```
error: function (xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Y hazlo así:

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function () {
        console.log(data);
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../Controllers/registro.php',
    data: data,
    //Cargando, le agregas un gif a un div
    beforeSend: function () {
        console.log("cargando")
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('nanananana');
        console.log("soy data"+data);
    },
    //Error que mostrará desde PHP
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hola buenos días, gracias por responder, usualmente  uso esta función pero esta vez la pase por alto porque la tarea era sencilla.
Use esta lineas para captar el error:
-error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow){

                        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
    
                 alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');
Y el error que me dio  fue este :
Not connect: Verify Network.
Dejo un pastebin con el código completo de la function error,
http://pastebin.com/LB0mFc7G

Comment: No, está mal, no puedes captar el error de esa forma, ya que con esa función solo imprimes 'Not connect: Verify Network.' en un alert, haz lo que te digo e imprime el error con "console.log(xhr.responseText)" solo de esa forma verás que retornó PHP y podrás ver en qué línea se cae (siendo un error)

Comment: Me retorna undefined al hacerlo, como tu me dices

Comment: Le agregó              error: function(xhr)  ?? e imprime todo el json de error console.log(xhr);

Comment: SI se lo agregue error: function(xhr)  como lo recomendó pero, solo me genero el undefined, en el console.log(xhr)

Comment: que extraño, pero te recomiendo siempre programar en base a errores con ajax. probaste el código con variables estáticas y usar el php sin el ajax?

Comment: Hola Luis, ya encontré la solución, el tema  como lo entiendo era que  el evento del btn que envía la petición  se quedaba activo lo cual impedía que le retornaran el data al ajax, pase por alto que el btn tenia un type="submit", al cambiarlo al type="button" se soluciono el problema.
Aveces uno da cosas por echo, pero bueno este tipo de situaciones solo ayudan a mejorar y ser mas precavidos con este tipo de cosas.

Comment: aa que bien, si usas button recuerda agregar un return en cada función de JS para que no provoque redirecciones

Answer (score 0):

`return` en tu "Controllers/registro.php" devuelve a la línea de código desde donde haya sido llamado; esto es: nunca sale de PHP.

Si quieres que lo que genera un código PHP sea devuelto a una llamada por AJAX tendrás que hacerlo como si fueras a pintarlo en el navegador, por ejemplo `echo $t` en lugar de `return $t`.